# Slideshow with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I was wondering if there was anyway to make a slideshow of images with a countdown timer on the slideshow.

I am making an exercise app, and need a course option. On the course option it is going to show an exercise for 20 seconds, then rest for 10 seconds etc. until the end of the course.

I have all the exercises ready, in images. I just need a code to show an image slideshow, with a countdown timer with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slideshow with a timer would be using a `setInterval()` method. Try this:

```
<img src="some_source/to/file.png" alt="text" />
```

Then you can run a function to change its src attribute as

```
setInterval(changeAttr, 20000);
function changeAttr() {
  $('img').attr('src', 'next_image.png');
}
```

You can use an `if else` block to change the image something like:

```
if($('img').attr('src') == 'some_image_file.png') {
  $('img').attr('src', 'new_image_file.png');
}
```

Now the timer would execute each 20 seconds and will change the image's source attribute. It will use an if else block to determine which image to be set as the slideshow image.